# WKB formula and Langer correction

Tags: schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue, approximations, semiclassical

The general WKB approximation formula states that
$$
\int_a^b\sqrt{E_k-V(x)} = (k+1)\pi \text{ with } x \in [a,b]
$$
for a regular Schrödinger equation (without the $\hbar$ and such). However, in the special case of a radial equation, there exists a Langer correction
$$
\ell(\ell+1) \rightarrow \left(\ell+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2
$$
as explained for example at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langer_correction and in more detail at http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205122 , but I can't seem to find an analogue easy explained formula as above in the special case of a radial Schrödinger equation.

**Edit**

The duplicate link explains why there is a shift, but I still don't know if there is a formula analogue to the WKB formula. Do we have to change the right hand side? Does applying the shift makes the formula work? Is there need of a transformation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148255/2451

Comment: Comment to the question (v4): The question formulation is ambiguous in several places. E.g. analogue to _which_ WKB formula?